# Why process.MainWindowTitle returning empty strings?

Tags: c#, process

Excel is spawning a lot of zombie process in task manager and the below is intended to kill them.

I have this helper method:

```
//helper method to kill zombie excel processes
private void KillSpecificExcelFileProcess(string excelFileName)
{
  var processes = from p in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
                  select p;

  foreach(var process in processes)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{2} MainWindowTitle {0} {1}",process.MainWindowTitle,(process.MainWindowTitle == "Microsoft Excel - " + excelFileName).ToString(),excelFileName);

    if(process.MainWindowTitle == "Microsoft Excel - " + excelFileName)
      process.Kill();
  }
}
```

This is written to the console:

[image]

So the method is finding the Excel processes ok but `process.MainWindowTitle` is an empty string - why is this?

edit
Excel is opened in the console like so:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

then inside the class:

```
this.xlApp = new Excel.Application();
this.xlApp.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this Excel processes are started by code so they don't have a GUI, hence they don't have a Window Title.

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle):

> A process has a main window associated with it only if the process has a graphical interface. If the associated process does not have a main window (so that MainWindowHandle is zero), MainWindowTitle is an empty string ("").

Comment: can I refactor the method so it gets a handle on each process ? I'd like to kill these excel processes but want to only kill the processes connected with the program.

Comment: @whytheq What you mean with "connected with the program"?

Comment: ... other console application might be running excel processes on this box. So I would only like this console to kill processes connected with the excel files that it has been manipulating.

Comment: @whytheq How do you open Excel from the console?

Answer (score 2):

The `process.MainWindowTitle` gets the caption of the main window of the process in the format:

> [filename] - Excel

In your example, the `process.MainWindowTitle` property is equal to

> Control.xlsm - Excel

and NOT "Microsoft Excel - Control.xlsm". If the problem persists, then consider matching `process.MainWindowTitle` to an empty string!

Comment: I'm testing now - will the visibility mentioned by king.code still be a factor?

Comment: ok - I think because the workbook/application get closed before I need to kill these zombie processes what I can (maybe) do is store the process id when all is still open. Then once wb/xl are closed use the id to kill the process?

Comment: So how do you terminate `xlApp`? Have you tried `xlApp.Quit();`? If so, what happens?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will post what I've implemented.

Answer (score 0):

So rather than relying on the file name - which is not visible after the workbook and Excel application have been closed - I store the process Id when manipulating the xl file. Then after the book and app have been closed I use this Id to close the zombie process.

```
//get Id when workbook/xlApp are still visible
private int getExcelFileProcessId(string excelFileName)
{
  int procId = -1;
  var processes = from p in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
                  select p;

  foreach(var process in processes)
  {
    if(process.MainWindowTitle == excelFileName + " - Excel")
    {
      procId = process.Id;
    }
  }

  return procId;
}

//helper method to kill zombie excel processes
private void KillSpecificExcelFileProcess(int anId)
{
  var processes = from p in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
                  select p;

  foreach(var process in processes)
  {
    if(process.Id == anId)
    {
      process.Kill();
    }
  }
}
```